# difference between following jquery and requireJS functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to know the difference between following javascript functions. Can someone help whats the difference and in what circumstances do we need to use these two functions?

```
define(function () {

});
```

the second one is self executing function which is below

```
(function() { })();
```

**Update**

I am using requireJS

Comment: Is the first one even valid in vanilla JS? Or are you using some library/plugin other than jQuery?

Comment: `define` is not a Javascript keyword or built-in function. Are you using `requireJS`? If so, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350699/explanation-of-define-of-the-requirejs-library).

Comment: yes I am using requireJS

Comment: I don't know requireJS but what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title mentions a "jQuery function" but there is no jQuery in the code you've shown.

The first bit of code:

```
define(function () {

});
```

...calls a function named `define` and passes an anonymous function as a parameter (some kind of callback?)

The second:

```
(function() { })();
```

Defines an anonymous function and calls it immediately.

> *"whats the difference and in what circumstances do we need to use these two functions?"*

Consult the RequireJS API documentation for guidance on when to use the `define()` function. As for an immediately-invoked-anonymous-function as in your second example there are many different reasons why you might use such a structure, e.g., a common reason is to create working variables and/or nested functions without creating globals.

To my way of thinking comparing the two (without more context, anyway) doesn't make any more sense than comparing `setTimeout(function(){ },1)` with `(function() { })();` (or comparing any other random function that takes a function as a parameter).